# How to override the typehint for entityTypeManager with a more specific one?

Tags: 9, coding-standards

I'm often frustrated by `entityTypeManager` because when I load entities, the typehint for the return value of the load methods is `EntityInterface`, but I want it to be a more specific interface (which I know it will be because I am loading a specific entity type with `getStorage`).

So, for example, consider this code adapted from the Flag module:

```
  /**
   * Loads flagging entities given their IDs.
   *
   * @param int[] $ids
   *   The flagging IDs.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\flag\FlaggingInterface[]
   *   An array of flaggings.
   */
  private function getFlaggingsByIds(array $ids): array {
    return $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('flagging')->loadMultiple($ids);
  }
```

PHPStan points out that there is a return type mismatch here because the doc comment is `FlaggingInterface[]` but `loadMultiple()` resolves to `EntityInterface[]`.

I can fix this by rewriting as follows:

```
$ids = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('flagging')->loadMultiple($ids);
/** @var \Drupal\flag\FlagInterface[] $ids */
return $ids;
```

But then I have to introduce an extra variable just to get the correct typehint.  Is there a more efficient way to override the typehint in this kind of case?